# CardDAV and CalDAV for Office 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2016, microsoft-office-2016

I saw a related question but it was from 2016. I am wondering what the best CardDAV and CalDAV sync/clients there are for Office 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[caldavsynchronizer.org](http://caldavsynchronizer.org/) is an open source working solution for me with office 2016/windows-10